# Call another portlet from renderMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I want to call another portlet from renderMapping of one portlet. How can i do it. Code snippet is as follows:

**Portlet 1:**

```
@RenderMapping
    public String handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Model model) {
        if(!admin){
         return "index"
        }
        else{
        //i have to call the rendermapping method of Portlet 2 and need to redirect to portlet 2
        }
    }
```

How can i call the **portlet 2** .

Answer (score 0):

For maintainability reasons you shouldn't. If both use common code, extract it into a common implementation that both call into. That's the proper way of code reuse. If both portlets are in the same plugin, there will also be no classloading issue and this is a very easy option. Everything else (calling the render method of a totally different portlet) is not your business - leave it purely to the portlet container and don't go there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. There's a reason why the portlet lifecycle has two phases, the ACTION and the RENDER phase.

If you want to redirect to another portlet, you'll have to use the action phase, so you'll need to create an action URL which can be clicked on, in the action phase you can do something like this:

```
@ActionMapping("goToDetail")
public void goToDetail(@RequestParam(value = "id") Long id, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){
    response.setEvent("detailTask", id);
}
```

In this action phase we set an event, which triggers the portlet wires, so you'll have to configure those properly in your **portlet.xml** (supported publishing/processing events) and then you probably have to configure something on Liferay as well.